# Images correct in .ps file but not displaying in .pdf

Tags: image, figure, texmaker

I'm using Texmaker 3.1 and having trouble getting my figures to show up in the PDF output.  My QuickBuild setting is "LaTeX + dvipdfm + View PDF" (I've also tried "LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF") and my images are .eps files in the local directory. The images all open as expected elsewhere (e.g., in GhostView), so the files themselves are okay.

There are no errors, but the resulting PDF file shows the figure captions with a white space where the image should appear (Note: I do not have the `draft` option set in the `\documentclass` command). My MWE is very simple; hence, I suspect the problem lies in Texmaker or somehow in my setup:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This is an example of an image within a figure not appearing where it should.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=3.in]{notworking.eps}
\caption{This caption should accompany an image.}
\label{fignotworking}
\end{figure}
```

And the following is an example of the image by itself (outside of a figure) not showing up either:

```
\includegraphics[width=3.in]{notworking.eps}

\end{document}
```

I looked at the resulting .ps file, and images show up correctly there. But if the problem lies somewhere in the ps2pdf stage, I have no idea how to correct it.  I would expect that a faulty ps2pdf.exe would cause more fatal problems than just images not showing up.